# java adding program: two consecutive zeroes would cause the total of all the values input to be printed and the program to be terminated

Tags: java

I want to make the program work on the 0-0 case. When I input 0,it will show the subtotal 0 first, and then I need to input another 0 to display the total 0, but in my program, when I input 0, it will only show total 0.(a zero value would cause subtotal to be printed and reset to zero)

```
class Adding{
    public static void main(String[] args){
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        int subtotal = 0;
        int total = 0;

        while(true){
            while(true){
                int number = input.nextInt();

                if(number == 0)break;
                subtotal = subtotal + number;
            }
            total = total + subtotal;
            if(subtotal != 0){
                System.out.println("subtotal: " + subtotal);
                subtotal = 0;
            }else{
                System.out.println("total: " + total);
                break;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Do you mean you need numbers to be together or only zeros to be together

Comment: when i input 0 > enter > subtotal: 0 > input another 0 > total: 0

Comment: can you give series of numbers as input and explain us what you are expecting and what is actually happening?

Comment: @baekbb could you add current output and expected output plz

Comment: as i understood you need to add another `input.nextInt();`  after the first loop ends. to add the read value and add it to the total .

Comment: example 1:                                                                                                4
3
2
0
subtotal: 9
13
-10
0
subtotal: 3
4
0
subtotal: 4
0
total: 16                                                                                                          example 2:                                                                                                  0
subtotal: 0
0
total: 0

Comment: If a user enters two consecutive zeroes then your program should terminate after printing total. For the first zero you want to print subtotal. For the second zero, print total. Is it right.

Comment: @Satya yes, thats what I want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is happening because of your condition `subTotal!=0`. When you enter `0` as first input, obviously your subtotal will be `0`. So it will skip printing your `subtotal:0` and directly prints `total:0`. So keep track or number of inputs you have read. If `subTotal!=0` or if this is your first input, then print `subTotal`.

So I have added `numbersRead` to keep track of number of characters you read. (You can do this even with a simple boolean).

Change your code to this:

```
class Adding{
    public static void main(String[] args){
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        int subtotal = 0;
        int total = 0; 
        int numbersRead=0;
        while(true){
            while(true){
                int number = input.nextInt();
                numbersRead++;
                if(number == 0)break;
                subtotal = subtotal + number;
            }
            total = total + subtotal;
            if(subtotal != 0 || numbersRead == 1){
                System.out.println("subtotal: " + subtotal);
                subtotal = 0;
            }else{
                System.out.println("total: " + total);
                break;
            }
        }
    }
}
```